# WEKA classifier take 12 hours

Tags: weka

I have an arff file with 6000 columns and 6000 rows. WEKA CLI takes 12hrs to come back with results. I'm wondering if I make the file sparse format will that improve the time or is just because of the sheer amount of data and there's nothing I can do?

Comment: Why wonder? What happens when you try that?  What error or other undesirable behavior do you encounter?

Comment: why wonder you ask. I guess you're right, I need to tweak my code that generates the arff files and I guess I just wanted some clarification of potential success before I embarked on that particular journey...

Answer (score 0):

The sparse format makes sense when your data has many zeros in it. If this is the case, you should see a considerable speed up, especially when a normal run takes 12 hours. If there are no zero or empty values in your data, the sparse format won't bring any benefit.

Comment: 1) Is your data suitable for sparse format?
2) Have you tried it in the meanwhile and achieved better results?

Comment: Just eyeballing it and yes it looks as if it is suitable as there are lots of 0's. I havent tried it yet - will do next week and post back here. Thanks.